# How to deploy a SpringBoot Application to Google App Engine?

Tags: spring, google-app-engine, spring-boot

How to deploy a SpringBoot REST Application to Google App Engine and intelij

I try follow this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=751iGaVX2Rc
but in some point I got:

> Requested Resource is not available

It is described here:
http://nixmash.com/java/deployable-wars-in-spring-boot-intellij-and-gradle/

What is best way to deploy app to:[google app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use App Engine Maven Plugin

add App Engine Maven Plugin and run this comand line:

> appengine:deploy

```
Stages and deploys an application to App Engine.
```

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/maven-reference

here is tutorial
https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/deploy-flex